# Google Drive strange prompt

Tags: mac, google-apps, google-sync

**Hardware**: Macbook pro 13-inch, M1, 2020

**OS**: Ventura 13.0.1

**Google Drive sync options**: file mirroring on a single folder

**symptoms**: when I delete a file from any folder on my mac, then I hit cmd+z to undo the delete and I get a strange prompt from drive

"Do you want to move the file from Google Drive? The file will be moved into the local folder. The copy from Drive will be moved to the trash"[1]

Can anyone reproduce this issue? Is this a bug or am I doing somwthing wrong?

[1] I translated the prompt message from Italian to English, so it might not be completely accurate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution

1. disconnect from drive
2. eliminate drive and all the linked directories
3. delete the local copy of the files
4. re-sync everything

Remember to check if your local folder is synched with the online drive (there must be the green badges close to the files in the local directory)